# Jquery being applied to all divs with same class but needs to do each indivudally

Tags: jquery, carousel, slide

I have some jQuery that when you click on an image in a carousel the image fades into a youtube/vimeo video.

However when you click the first image and it fades in the video, this is being applied to each carousel slide and fades the video in on all slides. Is there a way so that it does this on each slide individually?

```
$('.videoImage').click(function() {
            $('.videoImage').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(".videoContainer").css("display","block");
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li>    
    <div class="videoImage">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/920/500"/>
    </div>
    <div class="videoContainer">
        <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/g3J4VxWIM6s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="videoImage">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/920/500"/>
    </div>
    <div class="videoContainer">
        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/17914974" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` to get the current selected dom ,and find `next .videoContainer`

```
$('.videoImage').click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
               $(this).next(".videoContainer").css("display","block");
            });
        });
```